# dynamic generation of text field and the corresponding label based on the drop down selection

Tags: javascript, select

If the user selects drop down,flight no, only one text field and the corresponding label should come in. If the user selects drop down, all, many text fields should be generated such as for getting the input for flight no, source from, destination and so on.    "I want it to be done using JavaScript",

> The following code works as per my requirement but how to prevent the select from moving away from the normal table alignment,

**"Once, on change event is invoked,drop-down selection is made,the required fields are generated as per the selection is made but the select,drop-down moves away from the normal alignment in the resultant. "how to prevent this from happening and why does this happens???"**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>hide/show</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function display(obj,id1,id2)
        {
            txt=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
            document.getElementById(id1).style.display='none';
            document.getElementById(id2).style.display='none';
            if(txt.match(id1))
            {
                document.getElementById(id1).style.display='block';
            }
            if(txt.match(id2))
            {
                document.getElementById(id2).style.display='block';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Type:</td>
                <td class="field">

                    <select name="type" onchange="display(this,'text','image');">
                        <option>Please select option</option>
                        <option value="image">image</option>
                        <option value="text">texts</option>
                        <option value="invisible">invisible</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-center" colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"/>
                    <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody id="text" style="display: none;">
            <tr>
                <td class="title" rowspan="3">Text Color:</td>
                <td class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="color" size="8" maxlength="7"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody id="image" style="display: none;">
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Image:</td>
                <td class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="image" size="15"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="title">X Coordinates:</td>
                <td class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="x_coordinate" size="15"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="title">Y Coordinates:</td>
                <td class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="y_coordinate" size="5"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="title">Text Color:</td>
                <td class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="color" size="8" maxlength="7"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Display:</td>
                <td class="field">
                    <select name="diplay">
                        <option value="visitors">Visitors</option>
                        <option value="hits">Hits</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please specify the application which you are developing, the platform and the tool you are using to develop it. Also please explain what you have tried so far. so that anyone can analyze it easily and provide a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `variable_name.setVisible(boolean_value)` property to hide or unhide the elements depending upon the criteria. If you want to hide a search button, you can use `JsearchButton.setVisible(false);` Here JsearchButton is the variable name of the search button. Please see the example i wrote for your requirements. I hope this is useful.

This constructor initially makes all the elements invisible as soon as the application starts.

```
  public class AirportForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form AirportForm
     */
    public AirportForm() {
        initComponents();
        FlightNo.setVisible(false);
            EnterFlightNoTextBox.setVisible(false);
            From.setVisible(false);
            To.setVisible(false);
           SelectFromStationDropDown.setVisible(false);
           SelectToStationDropDown.setVisible(false);
    }
```

This is the code for your drop down user selection. Depending upon the user selection, the elements will be displayed.

```
private void SelectSearchCriteriaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String search1="Flight No";
    String search2="All";
    String search3="Select An Item";

    if(SelectSearchCriteria.getSelectedItem().toString()==search1){
        FlightNo.setVisible(true);
        EnterFlightNoTextBox.setVisible(true);
        From.setVisible(false);
        To.setVisible(false);
       SelectFromStationDropDown.setVisible(false);
       SelectToStationDropDown.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(SelectSearchCriteria.getSelectedItem().toString()==search2){
        FlightNo.setVisible(true);
        EnterFlightNoTextBox.setVisible(true);
        From.setVisible(true);
        To.setVisible(true);
       SelectFromStationDropDown.setVisible(true);
       SelectToStationDropDown.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is for declaring elements

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField EnterFlightNoTextBox;
private javax.swing.JButton FinalSearchButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel FlightNo;
private javax.swing.JLabel From;
private javax.swing.JComboBox SelectFromStationDropDown;
private javax.swing.JComboBox SelectSearchCriteria;
private javax.swing.JLabel SelectSearchType;
private javax.swing.JComboBox SelectToStationDropDown;
private javax.swing.JLabel To;
// End of variables declaration
```

Comment: Web application for the airport, using netbeans in windows7, I want to perform search based on the drop down selection and based on selection. Various fields has to be generated

Comment: thanks for the specification, but how to implement it in "jsp page". could it done using javascript and using simple buttons,html buttons,drop-down, i am not that much aware about Jbuttons but thanks in advance. and special thanks to @Maruthi for jotting down the code for me